How can I connect an op amp to amplify a small AC signal?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I am having trouble properly connecting an LM358N op amp to amplify a small AC signal. I tried connecting the positive side of my signal to the non-inverting input and the negative to ground. One resistor is connected to the output and the other side is connected to the inverting input. The other resistor is connected to the inverting input and the other side to ground.
I connected a 9V battery to Vcc and ground. I measure the output signal between ground and output. I see the signal as 7V so it seems it’s just the battery output. What am I doing wrong?

Welcome. Please provide a schematic.

It sounds like you are not biasing the amplifier correctly - as others say, please post a schematic.

Both inputs must satisfy the Vcm range and be DC biased  with an R2 added so that the non-inverting gain is 1+R1/R2 ratio

Welcome, manylya. There's a schematic symbol you can click on allowing you to enter a schematic from your computer. It does not work well from mobile devices, but if must it would be better to make a neat drawing and photograph it than to try to use words.

Please provide your schematic and details about your AC input.You need to provide maximum information for getting a good answer

Welcome! How small is small? Please provide a number.

Ok I added the schematic. The ac input is 0.3Volts. It is the signal generated in the coil induced by another coil.

manylya, How does this revised circuit differ from the earlier version (other than the gain)?

The challenge of using "cookbook" circuits
Implicit bipolar power supply

I tried connecting positive side of my signal to non-inverting input and the negative to ground. One resistor is connected to output and the other side is connected to inverting input.the other resistor is connected to inverting input and the other side to ground.

A common issue in textbook circuits, e.g. a non-inverting amplifier, is the formal drawing of op-amps without any depicted power supply. By default, it is bipolar...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
... and the circuit works perfectly.

Explicit single power supply
However, novice electronics enthusiasts may mistakenly assume that a single-supply configuration is being used, leading to difficulties in understanding the circuit's behavior and potential troubleshooting issues. This is indeed the case here.

simulate this circuit
A common limitation of standard operational amplifiers is that their output voltage cannot reach the supply rails, particularly 0 V. This problem is even more pronounced in single-supply configurations, where the output cannot swing below ground.

Adding bias voltage sources
Then let's "raise" the op-amp input voltages to half (5 V) of the supply voltage and "lower" the op-amp output voltage by the same amount. For this purpose, we can connect bias voltage sources (Vbias1, Vbias2 and Vbias3) in series with Vin, R3 and RL.

simulate this circuit
The circuit behaves as a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of (R3 + R4)/R3 = 10.

Replacing the bias voltage sources with charged capacitors
In practical circuits, the so-called "coupling capacitors"  (C1, C2 and C3) serve as such  bias voltage sources. They are initially charged to 5 V here, and then their charge is kept relatively constant.

simulate this circuit
For the AC signal, the circuit behaves identically to the one shown in Schematic 3, as an amplifier with a gain of 10.

For the DC signal, the circuit behaves as an op-amp follower with a gain of 1; so it is stable enough. The AC input voltage source, capacitors and resistor R3 do not play any role, and we can remove them in the equivalent circuit below:

simulate this circuit
Adding a negative power supply
Let's finally introduce a second, negative power supply -V to the circuit. This significantly simplifies the design. Additionally, the gain is frequency-independent.

simulate this circuit


Great answer sir Cyril, +1!

This specific amplifier has ground as an input so it can work with single power source.

@manylya, Can you explain that further?

"novice electronics enthusiasts may mistakenly assume"  - one reason for that assumption I've noticed is that when datasheets loudly proclaim "single supply" novice users may assume they can use the op-amp in unmodified circuits designed for bipolar supplies. As the inestimable Tom Waits wrote:  “The large print giveth and the small print taketh away.”

Why is your output at 7V? Your AC signal swings above and below ground. The op-amp however has a single-ended supply, which means that the op-amp can't handle input or output signals that are below its V- voltage, that is, GND. So when your input goes negative the op-amp punts and does something unpredictable. This could be 'Phase Reversal', as explained on pp.8 of this LM358/324 app note (link).
Here's a sim demonstrating phase reversal in an LM358 (324).
Even if you had an ideal op-amp (which the LM358 certainly isn't), the best you could hope for is that the op-amp would reproduce the positive part of your waveform (try the Circuitlab sim - that's what it does.) That's because its output swing is limited to V+ and V-, or 9V and GND in your case. It's actually worse than that, as we'll see when we look closer at the LM358 below.
To correct both the input range and output swing issues, this op-amp needs to be re-biased to shift its operating point to mid-range. We'll get into how to do that too.
But first, the LM358.
Understanding the LM358 Limits
The LM358 (and 324) is an op-amp designed for single-supply operation, although it works fine on bipolar supplies too. 'Being designed for single-supply' means its input and output ranges include near V- supply voltage, making it more feasible for V- to be tied to GND than devices like the LM741.
Let's check on the LM358 inputs. Note 'Common Mode Voltage' from the Datasheet, below:

The table shows minimum voltage for inputs to be V-, which in your case is GND. Thus, applying input voltage below GND isn't guaranteed.
There seems to be a bit of hope for below-GND inputs as explained in more detail later in the Datasheet:

We can infer that with V- at GND, the inputs could go as low as -0.3V before things go pear-shaped (such as the phase reversal issue noted above.) So maybe you could apply your +/-300mV signal the (+) input. Seems like that's what you're trying to do.
However, even if, hope against hope, the op-amp doesn't misbehave with (-) below V-, there's still a problem: the output swing is limited. Let's see what the Datasheet says about that:

Oops. Swing is limited to [V+ -2V] (that is, 7V) down to V- + some voltage, depending on loading. This leaves us with a useable swing between 1V and 7V only, or 6V peak-to-peak.
Back to your circuit. Your gain is set to 11 (recall non-inverting Av = 1 + Rf/Ri).
Your input is +/-300mV. What would an 'ideal' op-amp do on a single-ended 9V supply?

Vin = -300mV: Vout = GND ('slammed' at the rail)
Vin =  300mV: Vout =  3.3V

What will an LM358 do?

Vin = -300mV: Vout = Something between 0 and 1V? It's undefined
Vin =  300mV: Vout =  3.3V

The Circuitlab sim is consistent with this, showing something near 0V for the below-ground input.
In short, what you show won't work as you hoped, not even if you switch to a better op-amp.
Let's fix it.
Re-Biasing the Op-Amp for Single-Ended Supply
To make this circuit work on a single-ended supply we need to re-bias the inputs so the LM358 operates in its useable common-mode input and output swing ranges.
Here's a couple of ways to do that (simulate it here):

Design Notes

Gain is set to -10 / + 10 instead of 11. (Sorry, Nigel.)

Both circuits set a midpoint bias of 4V. This gets the best possible LM358 output swing range with a 9V supply.

Both circuits AC couple the input.

The inverting circuit AC couples the input to (-), and biases the (+) to mid-point. (-) also gets biased to mid-point because of feedback.

The non-inverting circuit simply swaps the inputs. Note that (-) input is also AC coupled to GND, which reduces DC drive needed from the op-amp.


The non-inverting version is preferred if you need higher input impedance (e.g., for line-in audio.)
Result? With a +/-300mV input a +/-3V swing (6V peak-to-peak) is possible.
Can We Do Better?
Is our work done here? No. You can consider upgrading to a better 'rail to rail' op-amp, such as the LMV358 and re-bias to 4.5V to get very close to a full swing. Something to think about.
Could you use a split (bipolar) supply? Say, a second 9V battery to make -9V? Then all the issues go away: you have even greater output swing, and you don't need AC coupling.
And finally, one more thing. It's possible to use a current source and a resistor to level-shift the input (simulate it here):

This circuit adds a constant 32uA DC bias to the (+) input. This develops a constant 320mV IR drop across the 10k load resistor, lifting the input up so that -300mV is translated to -20mV.
It will work only if your load can tolerate a small DC current being fed to it. Since you mentioned that it's coming from a coil coupling this shouldn't be a problem.

What is the role of the 1k resistor connected in series with the input source in the non-inverting circuit? I ask because this reduces the gain of the circuit. In my opinion, it is redundant.

It sets the non-inverting AC gain to be 10 instead of 11. Note that the 10k has a low-impedance path to ground via the 10uF cap, so the 40k/50k influence is negligible.

I understand that this is the trick used in a 4-resistor op-amp differential amplifier to equalize the input gains. I just don't understand why this is necessary here.

To make the gains the same for both versions.

With a single 9V supply, where the op-amp has its negative supply pin tied to 0V (ground) and its positive supply connected to +9V, you are constraining the op-amp's output to lie within that range, 0V to +9V. In fact, depending on the op-amp model, it may be worse; the LM358, for example will have an output constrained to be within the range +20mV to +7.3V.
On top of that, the op-amp inputs have similar constraints. You shouldn't present any potential outside the range 0V to +7.3V or so, to an LM358 input.
Different op-amps will have different restrictions, and you must consult the op-amp's datasheet to find out what you can and can't do with it. It will describe parameters such as "output voltage range", "input voltage limits" or "input common-mode voltage range" or similar.
In your circuit, the input can swing above and below 0V, becoming negative some of the time, which is a violation of the requirement that the input never be less than the op-amp's negative supply (0V in this case). When this happens, the op-amp will not behave as you expect, and you shouldn't be surprised to find it doing strange things at the output.
Even if the input could handle negative potentials, you might expect the output to therefore also become negative periodically. It cannot though, because you haven't provided a negative supply to the op-amp.
These problems are easily remedied, by providing a negative supply to the op-amp, using a second voltage source:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that I've also increased resistor values by a factor of ten, because 1kΩ would be rather a heavy load on the op-amp output.
Now the input can be anything between −9V and +7.3V, and the output is able to swing freely between −8.98V and +7.3V. You can expect:
$$ V_{OUT} = V_{IN} \times \left( 1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2} \right) $$
Obviously this solution requires an additional voltage source, which is inconvenient. It is possible, though, to offset all signals so that they oscillate above and below some midpoint in between 0V and +9V (+0.45V). Then the op-amp would no longer be required to handle negative inputs, or to produce negative outputs. This technique is called "biasing".
For examples on the subject, see this answer, and this other answer.

If you want to amplify the small ac signal which is riding on a DC,please use the below circuit.This is a non inverting configuration.In this circuit an ac of amplitude 0.2V is riding on top of a DC of value 2V and a frequency of 50Hz.

Here you can see 3 HPF's shown in green color box.The cut off frequency of the filter is selected such that it should pass the 50Hz.
The simulation result is given below.

